# Update Query Throwing error

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have to tables T1 and T2. I want to update fourth coloumn in T2 from T1. The query is

```
update t1 
set   t1.price=(select price from (select t1.price 
                            from t2 
                            where t1.customer=t2.customer and t1.sku=t2.sku and 
                                  t1.weekno= t2.weekno) where rownum=1)
```

But it is throwing error invalid identifier t1.weekno. I tried couple of other ways but every time I am facing the same problem. I would be grateful to you if you can help me. Thank you

P.S : We are dealing with 5Million records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your query is you're referencing `t1.price` in your select statement in your correlated subquery.  There are a couple ways to resolve this.

One option is to use `MERGE` for this:

```
merge
into t1
using   (
        select  t1.customer as updatedCustomer, t2.sku updatedsku, t2.weekno updatedweekno, t2.price updatedPrice
        from    t1
            join    t2
                on      t1.customer = t2.customer and t1.sku=t2.sku and 
                              t1.weekno= t2.weekno
        )
on      (customer = updatedCustomer and sku = updatedsku and weekno = updatedweekno)
when matched then
update
set     price = updatedPrice;
```

- [Condensed SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7f36d/1)

Alternatively, you could update your correlated subquery to use t2.price:

```
update t1 
set price = (select t2.price 
             from t2 
             where t1.customer=t2.customer and t1.sku=t2.sku and 
                              t1.weekno= t2.weekno and rownum = 1)
```

Comment: Thank you..but we are talking about 50Million rows. Will it run faster ?

Comment: @RAVIKANTHREDDYGUDIPATI -- not sure I could answer that question without knowing more about your table structures, indices, and EXPLAIN plans.  I would think the `MERGE` statement would have a better performance as it uses a standard `JOIN`.  I generally suggest staying away from correlated subqueries.  Best suggestion, try and see what works best.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the t1 to from clause the subquery :

```
select t1.price 
                            from t1,t2
                            where t1.customer=t2.customer and t1.sku=t2.sku and 
                                  t1.weekno= t2.weekno
```

Comment: I guess its working but cannot confirm it...as there are millions of records but the query is running....

Comment: can you suggest any optimized way of doing the above one. Like using "Join" constructs ??